# Python 2.5 and sqlite3: DLL load failed

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.5

When I type

```
import sqlite3
```

in Python 2.5 interpreter (C:\Python25\Python), I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\QGIS\python\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "C:\QGIS\python\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Specified module not found.
```

A message box with the message "sqlite3.dll not found" appears (Original German message: "Das Programm kann nicht gestartet werden, da sqlite3.dll auf dem Computer fehlt. Installieren Sie das Programm erneut, um das Problem zu beheben.").

According to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), sqlite3 is included with Python 2.5 (I don't need to install it separately).

Also, when I look into directory C:\Python25\DLLs, I find sqlite3.dll there.

What can I do in order to fix this problem?

Note that I have 3 different versions of Python on my machine.

Comment: Your traceback does not agree with where you think Python is installed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing C:\QGIS\python from PYTHONPATH environment variable fixed the issue.

Before:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenLibraries\python;C:\opus\src;C:\PopGen;C:\QGIS\python;
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django
```

After:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenLibraries\python;C:\opus\src;C:\PopGen;
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the SQLite3 DDL file from the official [website](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and then save the file in the following location

C:\Users\RamWill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs

im using python 3.7